# Method that checks for all results in the ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an API to work with some slides and that's my routing:

```
  scope "/api/v1" do
    scope "/slides" do
      post "/" => "slides#create"
      get ":slide_id" => "slides#show"
      put ":slide_id" => "slides#update"
    end
  end
```

As you can see, there's just one `get` that expects the `:slide_id` parameter but and what if I want to display all results from that table? What should I do?

### What I thought about

```
  scope "/api/v1" do
    scope "/slides" do
      post "/" => "slides#create"
      get "/" => "slides#show_all" # here's the magic
      get ":slide_id" => "slides#show"
      put ":slide_id" => "slides#update"
    end
  end
```

Did you saw the "magic"? Anyway, I'm feeling that's not the best way to do what I want, but I don't see any alternative, just to check if the method `show` has some parameter, if so, then display just what the user wants, otherwise, displays everything.

Can you give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should call that action `index`. And yes, it's perfectly valid solution to have a separate action to display collection of records. The variant with additional parameter smells a bit... If you're in doubt, you can always have a look at some examples. [Twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your requirement well.

You can make routing as bellow.

```
scope "/api/v1" do
    scope "/slides" do
      post "/" => "slides#create"
      get "(:slide_id)" => "slides#show" # slide_id param is optional
      put ":slide_id" => "slides#update"
   end
end
```

And in show action, check whether slide_id parameter is passed or not.